# How to add interpolated NA values in a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, dataset, data-science

I have this dataframe (57 rows, 9 cols) called "newData" and I'm trying to replace the NA values with the interpolated approximations and plot the graph. I've tried using functions such as na.approx and interp1 but I haven't managed to do it. Any solutions on how I can tackle this?

| years | city | SO2 | NO2 | O3 | PM10 | PM2.5 | CO | Benzen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | Tirane | 6.30 | 23.83 | 55.79 | 35.44 | 19.24 | 0.43 | 3.95 |
| 2013 | Tirane | NA | 27.30 | 51.03 | 32.56 | 16.45 | NA | NA |
| 2014 | Tirane | 15.52 | 35.01 | 32.64 | 54.06 | NA | 0.85 | 2.76 |

Comment: @RonakShah This works (some values have been missed around 4) but it does transform the whole data frame to a list though, is there a way to keep it a data frame?

Comment: @RonakShah I did reassign it and returns a list (which needs transposing) as well as the columns years and city being lost during the assignment.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I added an example in my answer and it seems to work for it. I also removed `lapply` from the original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.approx` -

```
#Generate data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:10], a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
#assign random NA's
df$a[c(3, 5)] <- NA
df$b[c(1, 6, 7)] <- NA
#apply na.approx
df[-1] <- zoo::na.approx(df[-1])
df

#   id           a          b
#1   a -0.56047565         NA
#2   b -0.23017749  0.3598138
#3   c -0.07983455  0.4007715
#4   d  0.07050839  0.1106827
#5   e  0.89278669 -0.5558411
#6   f  1.71506499 -1.0260998
#7   g  0.46091621 -1.4963585
#8   h -1.26506123 -1.9666172
#9   i -0.68685285  0.7013559
#10  j -0.44566197 -0.4727914
```

Comment: Thanks, I only had to change it to 
df[-(1:2)] <- zoo::na.approx(df[-(1:2)]